# Grep context lines on a per pattern basis

Tags: unix, grep

Is there a way to grep (or equivalent) with before and after context lines on a per pattern (-e "pattern") basis instead of the -A -B -C applying to all matched patterns? For example if I have a text file as below

```
Line 1. pattern1
Line 2. Some text
Line 3. ...
Line 4. ...
.
.
Line x. pattern2
Line x+1. ...
.
```

I want grep to print Line 1, 2 and Line x. The only regular patterns that can be matched with a regex are pattern1 and pattern2.
if I use "-B 1" it also prints line x+1 which i do not want.

Thank you.

Comment: No. But using several grep invocations can do the trick.

Comment: You could use a *Schwartzian Transform*... number the lines and do your first `grep` with desired `-B` and `-A` contexts. Then do your second `grep` with different values. Then sort the combined output on line number and finally remove the line numbers.